# Aggregation pipeline slow with large collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a single collection with over 200 million documents containing dimensions (things I want to filter on or group by) and metrics (things I want to sum or get averages from). I'm currently running against some performance issues and I'm hoping to gain some advice on how I could optimize/scale MongoDB or suggestions on alternative solutions. I'm running the latest stable MongoDB version using WiredTiger. The documents basically look like the following:

```
{
  "dimensions": {
    "account_id": ObjectId("590889944befcf34204dbef2"),
    "url": "https://test.com",
    "date": ISODate("2018-03-04T23:00:00.000+0000")
  },
  "metrics": {
    "cost": 155,
    "likes": 200
  }
}
```

I have three indexes on this collection, as there are various aggregations being ran on this collection:

1. account_id
2. date
3. account_id and date

The following aggregation query fetches 3 months of data, summing cost and likes and grouping by week/year:

```
db.large_collection.aggregate(

    [
        {
            $match: { "dimensions.date": { $gte: new Date(1512082800000), $lte: new Date(1522447200000) } }
        },

        {
            $match: { "dimensions.account_id": { $in: [ "590889944befcf34204dbefc", "590889944befcf34204dbf1f", "590889944befcf34204dbf21" ] }}
        },

        {
            $group: { 
              cost: { $sum: "$metrics.cost" }, 
              likes: { $sum: "$metrics.likes" }, 
              _id: { 
                year: { $year: { date: "$dimensions.date", timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam" } }, 
                week: { $isoWeek: { date: "$dimensions.date", timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam" } } 
              } 
            }
        },

        { 
            $project: {
                cost: 1, 
                likes: 1 
            }
        }
    ],

    {
        cursor: {
            batchSize: 50
        },
        allowDiskUse: true
    }

);
```

This query takes about 25-30 seconds to complete and I'm looking to reduce this to at least 5-10 seconds. It's currently a single MongoDB node, no shards or anything. The explain query can be found here: https://pastebin.com/raw/fNnPrZh0 and executionStats here: https://pastebin.com/raw/WA7BNpgA As you can see, MongoDB is using indexes but there are still 1.3 million documents that need to be read. I currently suspect I'm facing some I/O bottlenecks.

Does anyone have an idea how I could improve this aggregation pipeline? Would sharding help at all? Is MonogDB the right tool here?

Comment: Does the full index fit in memory? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/

Comment: @KevinSmith Yes it does. Total index size is 2.1GiB on a VPS with 8GB. Not much running apart from MongoDB. Perhaps something to note is that if I remove the $group and $project stages, the query returns within 200ms.

Comment: Interesting, Does including `cost` and `likes` on the index help? that way it wouldn't need to go back and look up the document for the group

Comment: @KevinSmith Didn't help sadly; I added the execution stats to my question if that helps anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following could improve performances **if and only** if **precomputing dimensions** within each record **is an option**.

If this type of query represents an important portion of the queries on this collection, then including additional fields to make these queries faster could be a viable alternative.

This hasn't been benchmarked.

---

One of the costly parts of this query probably comes from **working with dates**.

- First during the `$group` stage while computing for each matching record the year and the iso week associated to a specific time zone.
- Then, to a lesser extent, during the initial filtering, when keeping dates from the 3 last months.

---

The idea would be to store in each record the year and the isoweek, for the given example this would be `{ "year" : 2018, "week" : 10 }`. This way the `_id` key in the `$group` stage wouldn't need any computation (which would otherwise represent 1M3 complex date operations).

In a similar fashion, we could also store in each record the associated month, which would be `{ "month" : "201803" }` for the given example. This way the first match could be on months `[2, 3, 4, 5]` before applying a more precise and costlier filtering on the exact timestamps. This would spare the initial costlier `Date` filtering on 200M records to a simple `Int` filtering.

---

Let's create a new collection with these new pre-computed fields (in a real scenario, these fields would be included during the initial `insert` of the records):

```
db.large_collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
    "prec.year": { $year: { date: "$dimensions.date", timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam" } },
    "prec.week": { $isoWeek: { date: "$dimensions.date", timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam" } },
    "prec.month": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y%m", date: "$dimensions.date", timezone: "Europe/Amsterdam" } }
  }},
  { "$out": "large_collection_precomputed" }
])
```

which will store these documents:

```
{
  "dimensions" : { "account_id" : ObjectId("590889944befcf34204dbef2"), "url" : "https://test.com", "date" : ISODate("2018-03-04T23:00:00Z") },
  "metrics" : { "cost" : 155, "likes" : 200 },
  "prec" : { "year" : 2018, "week" : 10, "month" : "201803" }
}
```

And let's query:

```
db.large_collection_precomputed.aggregate([
  // Initial gross filtering of dates (months) (on 200M documents):
  { $match: { "prec.month": { $gte: "201802", $lte: "201805" } } },
  { $match: {
    "dimensions.account_id": { $in: [
      ObjectId("590889944befcf34204dbf1f"), ObjectId("590889944befcf34204dbef2")
    ]}
  }},
  // Exact filtering of dates (costlier, but only on ~1M5 documents).
  { $match: { "dimensions.date": { $gte: new Date(1512082800000), $lte: new Date(1522447200000) } } },
  { $group: {
    // The _id is now extremly fast to retrieve:
    _id: { year: "$prec.year", "week": "$prec.week" },
    cost: { $sum: "$metrics.cost" },
    likes: { $sum: "$metrics.likes" }
  }},
  ...
])
```

In this case we would use indexes on `account_id` and `month`.

*Note: Here, months are stored as `String` (`"201803"`) since I'm not sure how to cast them to `Int` within an aggregation query. But best would be to store them as `Int` when records are inserted*

---

As a side effect, this obviously will make the storage disk/ram of the collection heavier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, precalculating as much as possible seems to be the way to go.